# Why does Python sometimes upgrade a string to unicode and sometimes not?

Tags: python, unicode

I'm confused.  Consider this code working the way I expect:

```
>>> foo = u'Émilie and Juañ are turncoats.'
>>> bar = "foo is %s" % foo
>>> bar
u'foo is \xc3\x89milie and Jua\xc3\xb1 are turncoats.'
```

And this code not at all working the way I expect:

```
>>> try:
...     raise Exception(foo)
... except Exception as e:
...     foo2 = e
... 
>>> bar = "foo2 is %s" % foo2
------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython console>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-1: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Can someone explain what's going on here?  Why does it matter whether the unicode data is in a plain unicode string or stored in an Exception object?  And why does this fix it:

```
>>> bar = u"foo2 is %s" % foo2
>>> bar
u'foo2 is \xc3\x89milie and Jua\xc3\xb1 are turncoats.'
```

I am quite confused!  Thanks for the help!

UPDATE: My coding buddy Randall has added to my confusion in an attempt to help me!  Send in the reinforcements to explain how this is supposed to make sense:

```
>>> class A:
...     def __str__(self): return "string"
...     def __unicode__(self): return "unicode"
... 
>>> "%s %s" % (u'niño', A())
u'ni\xc3\xb1o unicode'
>>> "%s %s" % (A(), u'niño')
u'string ni\xc3\xb1o'
```

Note that the order of the arguments here determines which method is called!

Comment: What Python version are you using?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [Python Language Reference](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting) has the answer:

> If `format` is a Unicode object, or if any of the objects being converted using the `%s` conversion are Unicode objects, the result will also be a Unicode object.

```
foo = u'Émilie and Juañ are turncoats.'
bar = "foo is %s" % foo
```

This works, because `foo` is a `unicode` object. This causes the above rule to take effect and results in a Unicode string.

```
bar = "foo2 is %s" % foo2
```

In this case, `foo2` is an `Exception` object, which is obviously not a `unicode` object. So the interpreter tries to convert it to a normal `str` using your default encoding. This, apparently, is `ascii`, which cannot represent those characters and bails out with an exception.

```
bar = u"foo2 is %s" % foo2
```

Here it works again, because the format string is a `unicode` object. So the interpreter tries to convert `foo2` to a `unicode` object as well, which succeeds.

---

As to Randall's question: this surprises me too. However, this *is* according to the standard (reformatted for readability):

> `%s`  converts any Python object using `str()`. If the object or format provided is a `unicode` string, the resulting string will also be `unicode`.

*How* such a `unicode` object is created is left unclear. So both are legal:

- call `__str__`, decode back to a Unicode string, and insert it into the output string
- call `__unicode__` and insert the result directly into the output string

The mixed behaviour of the Python interpreter is rather hideous indeed. I would consider this to be a bug in the standard.

Edit: Quoting the [Python 3.0 changelog](http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/whatsnew/3.0.html#text-vs-data-instead-of-unicode-vs-8-bit), emphasis mine:

> Everything you thought you knew about binary data and Unicode has changed.
>
> [...]
>
> - As a consequence of this change in philosophy, pretty much all code that uses Unicode, encodings or binary data most likely has to change. The change is for the better, as in the 2.x world there were **numerous bugs having to do with mixing encoded and unencoded text**.

Comment: And it is using the default encoding (ascii) to convert the unicode to str.

Comment: But, why doesn't it invoke \_\_str\_\_ on the unicode object in the first example and fail then?

Comment: @samtregar, in binary operations between one str and one unicode object, it always tries to promote the str to unicode via the ascii codec -- much like in bin ops between a float and an int it promotes the int to float for you.  But a formatting operator with the format being a str and the right-hand side an exception object obviously is NOT a "bin op between a str and a unicode"!-)

Comment: Surprising that I got two upvotes for an answer that was wrong. I fixed it. All clear now?

Comment: @Thomas Yeah, that helps - it's basically a special magic case.  The general case of some object with unicode in it doesn't work but the basic case of a first-class unicode object does.  Can you explain Randall's addition to my question?  I find that particularly surprising!

Comment: See my edits. +1 for a question that turned out way more interesting than it seemed!